# How can I select the item in xsl:for-each when the item being iterated is the item to select?

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the sample XML below I want to display a list of parameters:

**Parameters**
Param1
Param2
Param3

I know how to iterate over a complex element and display child elements but how do I display the values when it's a simple list.

Sample XML:

`test.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<config version="1.0.0" id="bob1">
  <parameters>
    <parameter>Param1</parameter>
    <parameter>Param2</parameter>
    <parameter>Param3</parameter>
  </parameters>
 </config>
```

XSL: (`test.xsl`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="config">
  <html>
  <body>
  
  <h3>Parameters</h3>
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:for-each select="parameters/parameter">
      <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="parameter"/></td></tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This just gives me empty cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the `for-each` you just need `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.